# getText and getAttribute getting null value for input field in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I entered a value in an autocomplete field, and i'm writing a test is the value is populated correctly.

But the result I am getting is either null or empty using both getText and getAttribute.

Below is the 3 way that I've tried based on question answered by others but none seems to work.

All are either returning empty or null back to me.

```
element(by.name("visitPurposeID")).getText().then(function(visitpurpose) {
            console.log(visitpurpose);
            expect(visitpurpose).toEqual('New Visit');  
          });
          element(by.name("visitPurposeID")).getAttribute('visitpurpose').then(function(visitpurpose){
              console.log(visitpurpose);
          })
        expect(element(by.name("visitPurposeID")).getAttribute('visitpurpose')).toBe('New Visit');
```

html for the element

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix"><input class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c64-611 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" matinput="" name="visitPurposeID" placeholder="Purpose of Visit" required="" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-autocomplete="[object Object]" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-placeholder="Purpose of Visit" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" id="mat-input-203" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true"><mat-autocomplete class="mat-autocomplete ng-tns-c64-611" ng-reflect-display-with="displayPurposeOfVisitFn(value)"><!----></mat-autocomplete><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c29-619 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false" id="mat-form-field-label-699" for="mat-input-203" aria-owns="mat-input-203"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><mat-label class="ng-tns-c64-611 ng-star-inserted">Purpose of Visit</mat-label><!----><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c29-619 ng-star-inserted"> *</span></label></span></div>
```

Is there any other way to capture text on input field?

Comment: Are you able to get the element? Also share the html so that I can suggest a better solution.

Comment: @Zohair I am able to get the element to sendkeys and select suggestion, just not able to get back what has been entered in the input. I have updated the question to include the html for the element

Comment: There is no value on your `HTML` snippet, could you please add with the expected text in the `DOM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below one

```
expect(element(by.name("visitPurposeID")).getAttribute('value')).toBe('New Visit');
```

hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks @Madhan. It works. So does this mean getAttribute('value') is a fix code and not suppose to change 'value' to something else? In my earlier code i was changing the name to something that I can easily refer to

Comment: what should I do if I wanted to do validation continuously? It seems only the first one giving correct value. The next expect is giving null. Do I use 'value' for all the getAttribute?

Comment: @hafizan Yes, Apply the same for all places.